# How to select records only if all matching records found in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle and I have two tables student_marks and student_subject as below:

[image]

[image]

Now I'm required to display the names of the students who only matched the below two criteria:

a) The student should have attended all three tests.

b) The student should have scored a minimum of 35 in all three subjects.

I'm able to select students who have attended all three tests using below query but I'm also getting **John** who have failed in History:

```
select * from student_marks where Name in
(
select Name from student_marks
group by Name having count(1)=3
);
```

Is there any query that could satisfy both the criteria and show the results??

Answer (score 2):

You can use a partitioned outer join and then aggregate and use `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT m.name
FROM   student_subjects s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN student_marks m
       PARTITION BY ( m.name )
       ON ( s.name = m.subject )
GROUP BY m.name
HAVING COUNT(s.name) = COUNT(m.subject)
AND    MIN(m.marks) >= 35
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student_subjects ( name ) AS
SELECT 'Math' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Science' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'History' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE student_marks ( name, subject, marks ) AS
SELECT 'John',     'Math',    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',     'Science', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',     'History', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alexa',    'Math',    90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alexa',    'Science', 80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alexa',    'Geography', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aron',     'Math',    35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aron',     'Science', 35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aron',     'History', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Danielle', 'Science', 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Danielle', 'History', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Danielle', 'Math',    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Danielle', 'Geography', 20 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | Aron |
> | Danielle |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=462f1b5345f31745cac4bc363ee8ef2a)*

Answer (score 1):

You can group by student and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT name
FROM student_marks
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subject) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_subject)
   AND MIN(marks) >= 35
```

You can remove `DISTINCT` from `COUNT(DISTINCT subject)` if a student may attend each test only once.

Comment: This fails if there are subjects in `student_marks` that are not in `student_subjects` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08ea47d2dbf13740c41029f60ec5b7ce)

Comment: @MT0 this does not fail because there are not subjects in student_marks that are not in student_subjects. Did you invent subjects that are in student_marks in a foreign key that references student_subjects?

Comment: This does not fail with the OP's data set but, as I showed in the fiddle, if there are other subjects then it will fail as it does not correlate that you are counting the same subjects in each count.

Comment: @MT0 the data in your fiddle are invalid. A foreign key is not possible to contain values that do not exist in th eparent table.

Comment: The OP mentions no such foreign key; you are making an assumption that one exists between the two tables. If the `student_subjects` contains an list of the core subjects that all students are expected to master then you would expect students to also have marks in non-core subjects and no foreign key would exist.

Comment: @MT0 no, you are the one who would expect something like that in such a simple requirement. Non-core subjects! good one.